# .NET Portable Class Library [Serializable] Attribute

Tags: c#, serialization, appdomain, portable-class-library

I have a common class library containing many models for my server and my client. Since the client is running under Xamarin, the common library must be a Portable Class Library (PCL).

In my server, these objects are passed around with AppDomain Remoting/Marshaling, so to my understanding an object either needs to be marked as `[Serializable]` or inherit from `MarshalByRefObject`

Being in a PCL, I cannot do either of these things to any of my models.

My question is: How can I make these objects work with AppDomain Remoting/Marshaling and let them reside in a Portable Class Library?

Comment: Do you really need to serialize them as a binary object? Would converting them to JSON or XML work for your purposes so you can avoid this problem?

Comment: The Serialization is done automatically, by the proxy objects. Out of my control.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have created a PCL support library called *CSShim* that contains a "mock" `[Serializable]` attribute. If this library is referenced from *your* PCL library, you can use `[Serializable]` in your code.

Then, when you consume your PCL library in a regular .NET desktop application, the reference to the PCL *CSShim* is replaced with a reference to the .NET anolugue of *CSShim*, using the so-called ["bait-and-switch"](http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/) technique. The .NET analogue forwards the invocation of `[Serializable]` to the .NET implementation in *mscorlib* using [`[TypeForwardedTo]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.typeforwardedtoattribute.aspx).

*CSShim* is currently available from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/shim) for PCL profile 259, targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and higher, Windows 8 and higher, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8 and higher, Xamarin Android and Xamarin iOS.

The *CSShim* source code is available on [Github](https://github.com/cureos/shim). If it is a limitation that the PCL library only targets .NET 4.5 and higher, you could theoretically re-target the PCL library to a .NET Framework 4 profile such as profile 328, although re-targeting may be "a rough ride" :-)

Alternatively, you could create your own PCL support library containing only "mock" implementations of the types related to `SerializableAttribute`, and create a .NET analogue of the support library using type forwarding to invoke the valid types in the .NET core assemblies. I have outlined this approach in more detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21368529/650012) StackOverflow answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm. It feels like theres a library to do almost anything for .NET

Comment: In principle, yes, the library could be very much extended to cover a larger part of .NET. When I developed this library, I however concentrated on my own needs to facilitate PCL:ification of *AForge.NET*, *Accord.NET*, *Encog* and *fo-dicom*. But I happily encourage all user contributions that can help to extend the library further.

Comment: By the way, there is one limitation with regards to binary serialization and PCL, concerning the `[OnSerializing]` etc. attributes. Please see this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20666731/650012) for more information. Hopefully this is not a concern for you.

Comment: You're correct, I don't believe this really concerns me here, but thank you for the consideration!

Comment: I get System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'PCL' when I call stuff in System.IO, how do I use it? Edited: Aha okey, it is a dummy implementations of legancy code?